# Printing multi-line R output from PHP

Tags: php, r

I am using `venn()` of `gplots` package of R and I want to print the intersections on php. I am executing R using `exec()` and printing the output, it only prints last lines of a.

```
library(gplots)
f <- list(a, b, c, d, e)

info<-venn(f)
aa<-attr(info, "intersections")
print(aa)
```

Comment: Probably then you need to loop on your printing results. Since you have not provided us with any code i can only assume that your result is overwritten and you just see the last line.

Comment: venn(f)
a<-attr(f, "intersections")
print(a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take individual intersections and merge them in a single variable. You can try like this.

```
library(gplots)
f <- list(a, b, c, d, e)

info<-venn(f)
a<-attr(info, "intersections")$`A:B:C:D`
aa<-attr(info, "intersections")$`A:B:C:E`
aaa<-attr(info, "intersections")$`A:B:C:D:E`
a<-toString(paste(a,collapse=","))
aa<-toString(paste(aa,collapse=","))
aaa<-toString(paste(aaa,collapse=","))
x<-paste(a,aa,aaa,sep = "|")
print(x)
```